# How to use tsconfig-paths with ts-node

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig-paths

How do you setup paths with typescript to run with ts-node? And later compile paths to absolute paths when compiling?

I have following very minimal structure:
[image]

`koki.ts`:

```
export const calculate = (a: number, b: number) => {
  return a + b;
};
```

`index.ts`:

```
import { calculate } from "@koki/koki";

const result = calculate(1, 2);
console.log(result);
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"],
      "@koki/*": ["koki/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

I am getting:

```
ts-node src/index.ts 
Error: Cannot find module '@koki/koki'
Require stack:
- /home/pwnage/Documents/github/test-node/src/index.ts
```

Comment: You can't use the paths in `tsconfig.json` during runtime with node, at least by itself.  We do it with the `typescript-transform-paths` plugin, but that also requires using `ttsc` instead of just the default `tsc`.  But Node doesn't know anything about your tsconfig at runtime, so you need something that rewrites them during build.

Comment: that is with node, but i am also trying to run with ts-node, not compiling it and runing from dist.

Comment: You need tsconfig-paths to do that: https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/paths/

Comment: @Joe, hm, me and sensei use ts-node, so I don't understand why it does not do this simple transpiring work before call the nodejs.

Comment: I use "esm": true in ts-node section of tsconfig.json and tsconfig-paths/register along with typescript-transform-paths/register
But this still does not work

Comment: Ok, I got some understanding here: https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/imports
when I set ts-node esm mode, it pass import to nodejs as is. I need it because some packages esm only :-/ However, I think ts-node should keep but slightly transpile imports anyway, so it's kinda ts-node bug/flaw

Answer (score 15):

In my case, I added the `-r` option to `ts-node` scripts

`package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register src/index.ts",
}
```

`ts-node` works well in these codes

```
import { env } from "@/config/env";
```

Comment: where did `tsconfig-paths/resgister` coming from?

Comment: @zain https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths